# Jquery Dialog function executing onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my page loads it automatically reloads the page due to the dialog functions having window.location.reload() in one of them. I am new to making jquery dialogs so any corrections will help

Here is the code

```
       $("#CancelConfirmDialogDiv").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons:
            {
                "Yes": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    // redirect to the base admin/station page
                    var url = '@Url.Action("Users", "Admin")';
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                ,
                "No": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance

When window.location.reload() is commented out the page no longer refreshes the page

Comment: You are saying to code is being executed without the user clicking a button??

Comment: yes, that is what is happening

Comment: if you remove window.location.reload() the page doesn't reload?

Comment: Side note... You do realize you aren't redirecting to the Admin/Users page right?  Is this in a .js file or embedded in your html?  Because your @Url.Action won't work inside a .js.

Comment: Check your versions for compatibility first according to this outcome: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-dialog-buttons-executing-actions-before-dialog-is-rendered

Answer (score 0):

It was a version compatibility issue thanks Radio